# Allow user to change App Icon in React Native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Apple specifies that users can change their icon to give a more personalised experience. See docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/#user-selectable-app-icons

My question is regarding using this functionality in React Native. Building an app in React Native is it possible to access this `setAlternateIconName` method and provide the user with alternate app icons? Does React Native provide a nice way to interact with this IOS method?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently trying to build this out. This package seems designed to do what we both are looking for, but I haven't tried on anything that I have actually deployed yet.

https://github.com/skb1129/react-native-change-icon

Answer (score 0):

use can use this module [react-native-alternate-icons](https://github.com/kamsteegsoftware/react-native-alternate-icons), it allows to access to setAlternateIconName method